# Why SharedPreferences access time increases when Internet available? - Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Here is what I am trying to do:

In onCreate, I fetch data from sharedpreferences and display on list (I am using async task for this). This is working offline, no network required. So What is happening:

1. Internet On- Fetch string from sharedpreferences in about 1 sec.
2. Internet Off (Switched Off) - Fetch string from sharedpreferences in
   about few milliseconds (in almost no time)
3. Internet On- (Switched On
   again) - Fetch string from sharedpreferences takes between 1-3 sec
   and on some devices (Chinese) it takes around 1-30 sec.

I am trying to fetch only one string. Anybody faced similar?

Comment: Can you share your onCreate()? I haven't faced such issue, but maybe there will be something that can give us a hint.

Comment: maybe its not because the internet connection, but the RAM. if you turn on the connection, some background app that need internet connection will start working again, thus affect your RAM perfomance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AsyncTask` executes from a shared pool of threads. They will execute in order (sometimes, on different platforms).

`SharedPreferences` is on the device, so `AsyncTask` is not necessary. Take the call to it out of a background thread and back onto the UI thread and you should be fine.

`AsyncTask` should be used for tasks that you expect will take a lot of time to execute - and therefore you run off the UI thread.

In other words, fetching data from storage on the device should not be done this way.

Comment: Ok Yes AsyncTask was the main culprit. Actually I was doing parsing, and executing long list of statements. So I put that in Async. But It was taking time, as soon as I was setting internet on, other services start using resouces. Thats why performance was degrading. Now wrote code out of async and put that in onCreate itself. Thanks.